# Openlayers, features disapear after updating style

Tags: openlayers

I change features color on the fly I use this function at the end of `mounted` in `vue`

```
  existingFeatures.value.forEach(feature => {
    const color = "red"
    feature.setStyle(new Style({
      stroke: new Stroke({color: color}),
      fill: new Fill({color: color})
    }));
  })
```

For some reason features disapear after being updated

Answer (score 0):

answer: `setStyle()` will override all styles so I needed to set stroke too and radius

```
style.getImage().getFill().setColor(color);
  style.getImage().getStroke().setColor(color);
  style.getImage().setRadius(5)
```